# How to grep a yaml value

Tags: shell, grep, kubernetes, yaml

I try to get a value from a YAML file within a shell:

```
apiVersion: v1
items:
- apiVersion: v1
  kind: Pod
  spec:
    containers:
    hostIP: 12.198.110.192
    phase: Running
    podIP: 10.244.1.9
```

With `kubectl get pods -l run=hello-kube -o yaml | grep podIP:` I get this ouput:

```
    podIP: 10.244.1.9
```

My goal is to save that value in a Environment Variable, but I only get the `key/value`-pair:

```
export PODIP=$(kubectl get pods -l run=hello-kube -o yaml | grep podIP)
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

With awk:

```
kubectl get pods -l run=hello-kube -o yaml | awk '/podIP:/ {print $2}'
```

Output:

```
10.244.1.9
```

Comment: or with GNU grep: `| grep -Po 'podIP: \K.*'`

Comment: or if column 1 contains `podIP:` print column 2: `| awk '$1=="podIP:" {print $2}'`

Comment: This should also work. But with quotation marks around the output: `kubectl get pods -l run=hello-kube -o=jsonpath='{.items | .[].spec.podIP}'`

Answer (score 2):

You can also use `yq` (https://github.com/mikefarah/yq), which is a tool similar to `jq`.

Then do:

```
% yq read file.yaml items.0.spec.podIP
10.244.1.9
```

Comment: I would suggest [this yq version](https://github.com/kislyuk/yq) though. (`pip install -user yq`). It is exactly the same in syntax as `jq`

Answer (score 1):

You may also use the format json to get the value with jsonpath, something like,

```
kubectl get pods -l app=cron -o=jsonpath='{.items[0].status.podIP}'
```

Thanks